# PHP if isset($_POST doesn't work

Tags: php

I have a simple form on my page and I want to make sure every field is filled before inserting the values into the database. The problem is the condition never met, even if every field is filled I still get "Something is missing"...

```
Search:

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER[" PHP_SELF "]?>">
    <input placeholder="e-mail address" type="text" name="email_search">
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Go">

    <?php if (isset($_POST[ "search"])) { $email_search=m ysql_real_escape_string($_POST[ "email_search"]); $check=m ysql_query( "SELECT * FROM torzsvendegek WHERE email = '$email_search'"); $s=m ysql_fetch_array($check); }?>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER[" PHP_SELF "]?>">
        <table width="440" border="0" style="text-align:right;">
            <tr>
                <td>E-mail:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email_search;?>" disabled>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Név:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="nev" value="<?php echo $s['nev'];?>">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mikor:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="mikor">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Éjszakák száma:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="ejszakak">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Nemzetisége:</td>
                <td align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <select name="nyelv">
                        <option value="magyar" <?php if($s[ 'nyelv']=="magyar" ) echo "selected=\"selected\ ""; ?>>Magyar</option>
                        <option value="nemet" <?php if($s[ 'nyelv']=="nemet" ) echo "selected=\"selected\ ""; ?>>Német</option>
                        <option value="lengyel" <?php if($s[ 'nyelv']=="lengyel" ) echo "selected=\"selected\ ""; ?>>Lengyel</option>
                        <option value="roman" <?php if($s[ 'nyelv']=="roman" ) echo "selected=\"selected\ ""; ?>>Román</option>
                        <option value="szlovak" <?php if($s[ 'nyelv']=="szlovak" ) echo "selected=\"selected\ ""; ?>>Szlovák</option>
                        <option value="egyeb" <?php if($s[ 'nyelv']=="egyeb" ) echo "selected=\"selected\ ""; ?>>Egyéb</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Megjegyzés:</td>
                <td>
                    <textarea name="megjegyzes">
                        <?php echo htmlspecialchars($s[ 'megjegyzes']);?>
                    </textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <table width="440">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit_add" value="Hozzáad">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

    <?php if (isset($_POST[ "submit_add"]) && !empty($_POST[ "nev"]) && !empty($_POST[ "email"]) && !empty($_POST[ "mikor"]) && !empty($_POST[ "ejszakak"])){ $nev=m ysql_real_escape_string($_POST[ "nev"]); $email=m ysql_real_escape_string($_POST[ "email"]); $mikor=m ysql_real_escape_string($_POST[ "mikor"]); $ejszakak=m ysql_real_escape_string($_POST[ "ejszakak"]); $nyelv=m ysql_real_escape_string($_POST[ "nyelv"]); $megjegyzes=m ysql_real_escape_string($_POST[ "megjegyzes"]); $check2=m ysql_query( "SELECT * FROM torzsvendegek WHERE email = '$email'"); $br="<br>" ; if (mysql_num_rows($check2)> 0) { $adatok = mysql_fetch_array($check2); $osszesen = ($adatok['ejszakak'] + $ejszakak); mysql_query("UPDATE torzsvendegek SET nev = '".$nev."', mikor = '".$adatok['mikor']."".$mikor."".$br."', ejszakak = '".$osszesen."', nyelv = '".$nyelv."', megjegyzes = '".$adatok['megjegyzes']."".$megjegyzes."".$br."' WHERE email = '".$email."'"); echo "
    <br>".$email." Updated"; } else { mysql_query("INSERT INTO torzsvendegek (id, nev, email, mikor, ejszakak, nyelv, megjegyzes) VALUES (NULL, '$nev', '$email', '".$mikor."".$br."', '$ejszakak', '$nyelv', '".$megjegyzes."')"); echo "
    <br>".$email." Added"; } } else { echo "Something is missing"; } ?>
```

Comment: First of all: Don't use mysql_*! It's deprecated and extremely insecure. Use PDO() or mysqli() instead.

Comment: Why do you have two `<form>` tags?

Comment: Thanks for the comments guy. Th first form is just a search form, it fills parts of the 2nd form if a match is found in the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made 2 mistakes in your code:

1) You didn't close the first form (missing </form>)
2) You disabled the E-mail input field which resulted in always empty

Here's the updated (though deprecated and insecure!!!) code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["search"])){

    $email_search = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email_search"]);
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM torzsvendegek WHERE email = '$email_search'");
    $s = mysql_fetch_array($check);
}

if(isset($_POST["submit_add"]) && !empty($_POST["nev"]) && !empty($_POST["email"]) && !empty($_POST["mikor"]) && !empty($_POST["ejszakak"])){

    $nev = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["nev"]);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
    $mikor = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["mikor"]);
    $ejszakak = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["ejszakak"]);
    $nyelv = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["nyelv"]);
    $megjegyzes = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["megjegyzes"]);

    $check2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM torzsvendegek WHERE email = '$email'");
    $br = "<br>";

    if (mysql_num_rows($check2) > 0){
        $adatok = mysql_fetch_array($check2);
        $osszesen = ($adatok['ejszakak'] + $ejszakak);
        mysql_query("UPDATE torzsvendegek SET nev = '".$nev."', mikor = '".$adatok['mikor']."".$mikor."".$br."', ejszakak = '".$osszesen."', nyelv = '".$nyelv."', megjegyzes = '".$adatok['megjegyzes']."".$megjegyzes."".$br."' WHERE email = '".$email."'");
        echo "<br>".$email." Updated";
    } else {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO torzsvendegek (id, nev, email, mikor, ejszakak, nyelv, megjegyzes) VALUES (NULL, '$nev', '$email', '".$mikor."".$br."', '$ejszakak', '$nyelv', '".$megjegyzes."')");
        echo "<br>".$email." Added";
    }
} else {
    echo "Something is missing";
}

?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>">
    Search: <input placeholder="e-mail address" type="text" name="email_search">
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Go">
</form>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>">
    <table width="440" border="0" style="text-align:right;">
        <tr>
            <td>E-mail:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email_search;?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Név:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="nev" value="<?php echo $s['nev'];?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mikor:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="mikor"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Éjszakák száma:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="ejszakak"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nemzetisége:</td>
            <td align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <select name="nyelv">
                    <option value="magyar" <?php if($s['nyelv']=="magyar") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Magyar</option>
                    <option value="nemet" <?php if($s['nyelv']=="nemet") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Német</option>
                    <option value="lengyel" <?php if($s['nyelv']=="lengyel") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Lengyel</option>
                    <option value="roman" <?php if($s['nyelv']=="roman") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Román</option>
                    <option value="szlovak" <?php if($s['nyelv']=="szlovak") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Szlovák</option>
                    <option value="egyeb" <?php if($s['nyelv']=="egyeb") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Egyéb</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Megjegyzés:</td>
            <td><textarea name="megjegyzes"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($s['megjegyzes']);?></textarea></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table width="440">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit_add" value="Hozzáad"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. I still have a question tho. I still get the "Something is missing" message when opening the page, even though the Submit button was never pressed. How can I fix that?

Comment: Which are? And if the answer is what you were looking for, please accept it so it doesn't remain unanswered forever.

Comment: It's because the if statement always returns false when no form data is sent yet. You can fix it by removing the else part and including it inside the if statement itself. Like if(mysql..) else if(mysql.. == 0).. else { echo error;

Comment: But to be honest you don't need the else part at all. Useally you simply check if any of the vars are empty inside the if statement and display errors based on that. I'm more then happy to give you a much better example so you can learn, but you'll have to contact me through my profile (email is there) as this is not the place to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your search form tag to keep the two forms separated

```
Search:<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>"><input placeholder="e-mail address" type="text" name="email_search"><input type="submit" name="search" value="Go"></form>
```

and

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>">
<table width="440" border="0" style="text-align:right;">
<tr><td>E-mail:</td><td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email_search;?>" disabled></td></tr>
<tr><td>Név:</td><td><input type="text" name="nev" value="<?php echo $s['nev'];?>"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Mikor:</td><td><input type="text" name="mikor"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Éjszakák száma:</td><td><input type="text" name="ejszakak"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Nemzetisége:</td><td align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;<select name="nyelv">
<option value="magyar" <?php if($s['nyelv']=="magyar") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Magyar</option>
<option value="nemet" <?php if($s['nyelv']=="nemet") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Német</option>
<option value="lengyel" <?php if($s['nyelv']=="lengyel") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Lengyel</option>
<option value="roman" <?php if($s['nyelv']=="roman") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Román</option>
<option value="szlovak" <?php if($s['nyelv']=="szlovak") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Szlovák</option>
<option value="egyeb" <?php if($s['nyelv']=="egyeb") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Egyéb</option>
</select></td></tr>
<tr><td>Megjegyzés:</td><td><textarea name="megjegyzes"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($s['megjegyzes']);?></textarea></td></tr>
</table><br>
<table width="440"><tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit_add" value="Hozzáad"></td></tr></table>
</form>
```

Comment: You are right, I forgot to close the first form, fixed it, but it still does not work. :(

Answer (score 0):

You did not close your search form and you need to remove the disabled attribute from your email input field.

I re-wrote your code to help you will debugging. I commented out all the stuff related to the database so you can focus on the form fields only. Here is the code I re-wrote. I left comments so you can see what I did.

```
    <?php 
    /******JUST TO MAKE DEBBUGGING EASIER***/
    echo "<pre>"; // Start of the pre> tags


    /**ANYTHING TO DO WITH THE DATABASE I HAVE COMMENTED OUT**/
    if(isset($_POST["search"])){ 
        $email_search = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email_search"]);

        /**PRINT_R FOR DEBUGGING PURPOSES, REMOVE!!*/
        print_r($email_search);

        //$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM torzsvendegek WHERE email = '$email_search'");
        //$s = mysql_fetch_array($check);
    }

    /***CHECK THE POST DATA, REMOVE FROM APPLICATION ONCE YOU HAVE DEBUGGED THE DATA**/
    print_r($_POST);

    /***I WILL STORE THE POST DATA IN VARIABLES BEFORE CHECKING**/
    $nev        = isset($_POST["nev"]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["nev"]) : null;
    $email      = isset($_POST["email"]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]) : null;
    $mikor      = isset($_POST["mikor"]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["mikor"]) : null;
    $ejszakak   = isset($_POST["ejszakak"]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["ejszakak"]) : null;
    $nyelv      = isset($_POST["nyelv"]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["nyelv"]) : null;
    $megjegyzes = isset($_POST["megjegyzes"]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["megjegyzes"]) : null;


    if(isset($_POST["submit_add"]) && !is_null($nev) && !is_null($email) && !is_null($mikor) && !is_null($ejszakak)){
        /*******
            SINCE I ALREADY HAVE THEM, YOU NEED TO REMOVE THEM FROM THE CODE
            $nev = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["nev"]);
            $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
            $mikor = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["mikor"]);
            $ejszakak = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["ejszakak"]);
            $nyelv = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["nyelv"]);
            $megjegyzes = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["megjegyzes"]);
        ******/
        //$check2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM torzsvendegek WHERE email = '$email'");
        $br = "<br>";
        /*********
        if (mysql_num_rows($check2) > 0) {

            $adatok = mysql_fetch_array($check2);
            $osszesen = ($adatok['ejszakak'] + $ejszakak);
            mysql_query("UPDATE torzsvendegek SET nev = '".$nev."', mikor = '".$adatok['mikor']."".$mikor."".$br."', ejszakak = '".$osszesen."', nyelv = '".$nyelv."', megjegyzes = '".$adatok['megjegyzes']."".$megjegyzes."".$br."' WHERE email = '".$email."'");
            echo "<br>".$email." Updated";

        }else {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO torzsvendegek (id, nev, email, mikor, ejszakak, nyelv, megjegyzes) VALUES (NULL, '$nev', '$email', '".$mikor."".$br."', '$ejszakak', '$nyelv', '".$megjegyzes."')");
            echo "<br>".$email." Added";

        }
        ****/
    }elseif (isset($_POST["submit_add"])) {
        echo "Something is missing";
    }

    echo '</pre>';//end of pre
?>

Search:
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>">
    <input placeholder="e-mail address" type="text" name="email_search">
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Go">
</form>


<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>">
    <table width="440" border="0" style="text-align:right;">
        <tr>
            <td>E-mail:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Név:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="nev" value="<?php echo $nev;?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mikor:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="mikor" value="<?php echo $mikor;?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Éjszakák száma:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="ejszakak" value="<?php echo $ejszakak;?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nemzetisége:</td>
            <td align="left">
                <select name="nyelv">
                    <option value="magyar" <?php if($nyelv=="magyar") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Magyar</option>
                    <option value="nemet" <?php if($nyelv=="nemet") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Német</option>
                    <option value="lengyel" <?php if($nyelv=="lengyel") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Lengyel</option>
                    <option value="roman" <?php if($nyelv=="roman") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Román</option>
                    <option value="szlovak" <?php if($nyelv=="szlovak") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Szlovák</option>
                    <option value="egyeb" <?php if($nyelv=="egyeb") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Egyéb</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Megjegyzés:</td>
            <td><textarea name="megjegyzes"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($megjegyzes);?></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table><br>
    <table width="440">
        <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit_add" value="Hozzáad"></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed breakdown. I made good use of it. :) What is the benefit of using !is_null insted of !empty?

Comment: there is no difference. I just used !is_null because thats what I set in the short hand if statement. I could have used !empty if instead of assigning a null value, I just put an empty quote. Works the same.